# Find sum of adjacent columns that match value from first column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm attempting to find the total sum of every value adjacent to a column row that matches the same team name.

Example:
[image: Example]

Essentially I need the sum of the adjacent scores to each team put into column 'G' next to that team name. I plan to have 12-16 team names in column H, all being wildly different, so if I update the team name from column H, the formula should find that team name in column B and sum it's total scores from every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SUMPRODUCT` as per @Shrivallabha.redij

Here is an alternative that might be more appropriate to `Google SpreadSheets`, using `Filter` function.

Formula in `F3`:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:D,A:A=G3))
```

Drag down..

This would update scores when you add them.

Answer (score 4):

Following formula can be used in `Excel`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$E$7*($B$3:$B$7=$H3))
```

Adjust this to suit.

**Note:** The formula will work in `google-sheets` as confirmed by @JvdV.

Comment: @JvdV thank you so much for your inputs, I have updated my note accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here the formula that can be used:

```
= arrayformula(sumif(filter(B3:B,B3:B<>""),"=" &  
    filter(H3:H,G3:G<>""),C3:C)+sumif(filter(B3:B,B3:B<>""),"=" & 
    filter(H3:H,H3:H<>""),D3:D)+sumif(filter(B3:B,B3:B<>""),"=" & 
    filter(H3:G,H3:H<>""),E3:E))
```